# Passing a type as parameter to an attribute

Tags: c#, generics, custom-attributes

I wrote a somewhat generic deserialization mechanism that allows me to construct objects from a binary file format used by a C++ application.

To keep things clean and easy to change, I made a `Field` class that extends `Attribute`, is constructed with `Field(int offset, string type, int length, int padding)` and is applied to the class attributes I wish to deserialize. This is how it looks like :

```
[Field(0x04, "int")]
public int ID = 0;

[Field(0x08, "string", 0x48)]
public string Name = "0";

[Field(0x6C, "byte", 3)]
public byte[] Color = { 0, 0, 0 };

[Field(0x70, "int")]
public int BackgroundSoundEffect = 0;

[Field(0x74, "byte", 3)]
public byte[] BackgroundColor = { 0, 0, 0 };

[Field(0x78, "byte", 3)]
public byte[] BackgroundLightPower = { 0, 0, 0 };

[Field(0x7C, "float", 3)]
public float[] BackgroundLightAngle = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

Calling `myClass.Decompile(pathToBinaryFile)` will then extract the data from the file, reading the proper types and sizes at the proper offsets.

However, I find that passing the type name as a string is ugly.

Is it possible to pass the *type* in a more elegant yet short way, and how ?

Thank you.

Comment: The type is the same as the marked field, isn't it? Why not get the type from the field, instead of marking it in the attribute's constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `typeof` operator (returns an instance of `Type`):

```
[Field(0x7C, typeof(float), 3)]
```

Comment: @Heandel: Type safety and refactoring support in each attribute vs. six extra characters in each attribute == I'd go for the frown :-)

Comment: @Heandel, it's the only clean way of doing it... It's a bit longer, but it's 100 times better than using a string

Comment: I just divide the awesomeness of typeof by the awesomeness of string... as you can see, it's a very accurate estimation ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes: make the attribute take a `Type` as a parameter, and then pass e.g. `typeof(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the parameter must be of type `Type` and then you can pass the type as follows:

```
[Field(0x7C, typeof(float), 3)]
public float[] BackgroundLightAngle = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

Answer (score 2):

With C# 10 there is a [new feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10) (in preview at time of this post) that allows you to create generic attributes!

Using this new feature, you can create a generic attribute instead:

```
public class GenericAttribute<T> : Attribute { }
```

Then, specify the type parameter to use the attribute:

```
[GenericAttribute<string>()]
public string Method() => default;
```

Comment: This is C# 11 and still in Preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#generic-attributes

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to put the type in the constructor of the attribute, you can get it from the field. See the example:

```
public class FieldAttribute : Attribute { }

class Data
{
    [Field]
    public int Num;

    [Field]
    public string Name;

    public decimal NonField;
}


class Deserializer
{
    public static void Deserialize(object data)
    {
        var fields = data.GetType().GetFields();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            Type t = field.FieldType;
            FieldAttribute attr = field.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                     .Where(x => x is FieldAttribute)
                                     .FirstOrDefault() as FieldAttribute;
            if (attr == null) return;
            //now you have the type and the attribute
            //and even the field with its value
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: @Heandel: Maybe I misunderstood your idea. But a truth is, an attribute can't get its "hanger"'s information. In another word, you have an instance of some attribute called `a`, you can't tell which field/property/class  `a` is being marked.